# How to get the table name and column from mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a joined table in mySQL which looks like this.

```
SELECT junction_departments_qsps.departments_fk, junction_departments_qsps.checked, qsps.id, qsps.qsp_name, employees.id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name 

FROM junction_departments_qsps 

INNER JOIN qsps ON junction_departments_qsps.qsps_fk = qsps.id 

INNER JOIN employees ON employees.department_id = junction_departments_qsps.departments_fk 

WHERE junction_departments_qsps.checked = 1
```

As you can see I have a few table with the same column name "id".  In mySQL you link the table-name to the column-name like table-name.column-name.  In PHP I would usually get a column name by creating a loop and then echoing

```
$variable["column-name"];
```

Is there a way in PHP to get a table-name and column-name like in mySQL?  I've tried this

```
$variable["table-name.column-name"];
```

It doesn't work.

My problem with my joined tables is that when I do

```
$variable["id"];
```

I'm not getting the right id because I have multiple id's being asked for in mySQL.

Thank you really appreciate the help! :)

Comment: `junction_departments_qsps.departments_fk AS junction_departments_qsps_departments_fk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the alias syntax:

```
SELECT `id` as `object_id` FROM `objects`
```

I don't know if MySQL likes `.` in the alias, if it does, great!

Answer (score 0):

If u have the same column name in different tables, u can use AS in the query, e.g.

```
select a.id AS ida, b.id AS idb FROM tab1 a join tab2 b using(column)
```

In the result u have than

```
$data['ida];
$data['idb'];
```